# How do I fix uneven symmetry in texture paint

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I am still fairly new to Blender and this is the first model I've completed fully and started to texture paint. I created seams on the model's head and then did a UV unwrap. When I take the selected UV into texture paint, the UV appears on the left, but with another duplicate of each island underneath/over it that was not present in UV editor. When I create a material to paint on, the symmetry works, but the strokes are not aligned perfectly. Painting on the character's right side creates a mirrored stroke on the left side, but lower. Even if I reset the UV map, going into texture paint still shows an unaligned duplicate UV of the unwrapped shape.

Those duplicate islands only show up in Texture Paint Mode and not in UV editor mode. Thus, I cannot simply align them in UV editor, or separate them to avoid overlap, as they do not appear. Moving the islands in UV editor will also move those duplicates that appear in Texture Paint mode, but they will always be offset by a small distance. I am unsure how to align them. I have checked to see if my model is not aligned with the world origin, and I see nothing wrong. It is centered on all the axes.[image]
In UV editor, only one side of the model appears.

[image]
In Texture Paint mode, the UVs appear with some kind of duplicate that is always offset by a little bit. Is this supposed to represent the mirrored mesh created by the mirror modifier? If so, how do I align them when they don't appear in UV editor? I drew a pink stroke from the right going inward towards the center. A stroke on the left appears, but the symmetry is off.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in your *UV Editor*, the UVs are overlaying, but they are not aligned, so your painting is not aligned either. To have a perfectly symmetrical painting you need to either:

- Have UVs that are not overlaying. In your case you need to select the right or left part of your object and, in the *UV Editor*, move the UVs so they don't overlay, then in the *3D View* enable the *X Mirror* option on the top right and paint:

[image]

- Have UVs that are perfectly overlaying, which means that are aligned. To do that you can delete the right or left half of your object, give it a *Mirror* modifier, unwrap again and in the *UV Editor* rotate and scale the UVs in order to optimize the space, then apply the modifier and paint:

[image]

Comment: I should have clarified that I cannot move those unaligned islands of the mirrored side of the face. When I go into the UV editor, those duplicated islands that represent the mirrored side of the model do not show up. They only appear in Texture Paint mode. When I moved the UVs around in UV editor, it will move those unaligned duplicates with it in Texture paint mode, but they will always be offset. I'm unsure how to align them when they don't show up in UV editor. My model already has a mirror modifier enabled.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you can always move the UVs, please share your file so that we can test it